# ROS2 master-slave communication

Tags: ros

Currently I am working on a simple image transfer. I have a folder on the master (containing high-resolution images), and I need to transfer the images from the master to the slave through ROS2. Both equipment systems are Ubuntu 22.04, the ping connection is smooth, and they can be connected using ssh. The problem is that even if I set up a firewall and the same ROS_DOMAIN_ID, the two nodes still cannot communicate.

After selecting FastDDS, the node running demo_node can communicate successfully (hello world). But once I changed to my own publisher program, I couldn't connect to each other. Can anyone please provide suggestions or thoughts on this?